# Access to props passed by URL in React + Next.js + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I cannot find a way to access props passed by URL when using Typescript. Showing minimum code to illustrate the issue.

1. I am pushing a page with:

```
Router.push('/task/[uuid]', '/task/' + data.uuid);
```

2. And then in `/task/[uuid].tsx`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props); // {uuid: "", url: {…}}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props); // {uuid: "", url: {…}}
        if (!this.props.uuid) {
             throw new Error("Missing UUID");
        }
    }

    static getInitialProps({ req }: NextPageContext) {
        console.log(req); // undefined
    }

}
```

The weirdest thing is that when pushing the URL it throws the Error at first, showing error in the browser, but then *sometimes* it recovers after a few seconds and succeeds.

When calling the URL directly from the browser, uuid is correctly available both in the `constructor()` and `componentDidMount()`, but `getInitialProps()` is not even called.

My questions:

1. What is the correct way to do this?
2. There is props.url, which I could use as a workaround. What is the correct type to be able to access it?
3. Any idea why does it "recover" sometimes?
4. Why does it work when calling the URL directly from the browser?
5. Why is getInitialProps() not called when calling the URL directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `query`

```
static getInitialProps({ query }: NextPageContext) {
    console.log(query); // undefined
}
```